# Youtube iFrame video disables normal page href click events after iframe on iPhones

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I have this mobile site and only on iphones this happens: I have two links after the embedded iframe, and both fail or are disabled. If i remove the iframe they work as normal so somewhere in the iframe.. its preventing this or creating a hidden overlay. If i place the links about 200px beneath the iframe they are ok, but this is not ideal as theres a massive gap.

```
  <div class="js-video"><iframe src="???"></iframe></div>
  <div>
     <a href="??">link</a>
     <a href="??">link</a>
  </div>
```

The above is where the iframe prevents me from clicking on them.

```
  <div class="js-video"><iframe src="???"></iframe></div>
  <div style="margin-top:200px;">  
     <a href="??">link</a>
     <a href="??">link</a>
  </div>
```

Adding the margin top enables me to click on them but gives me a big gap.

Answer (score 0):

this also drives me nuts since two days... but now I found out that's a known Youtube/Google issue:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ipad&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=4569

Hopefully solved asap!

Comment: for me adding "&controls=2" is a temporary solution that works on iPhone - but the user has to click twice to start playing :/

Comment: Thanks for this will give this ago tomorrow and let you know, lets also see if they meet the may 22 date for completion.